# javascript random image on page load and change over a period of time

Tags: javascript, css, image, random

I'm trying to get this function to run when the page is loaded so that the images will change over a period of time. I can get this image to run onclick but it can't find a way for it run on load, i've tried everything I can find to try and do it

```
    var imgArray = []
            imgArray[0] = "url('../danallenfilms/images/screenshots/husky/shot1.png')";
            imgArray[1] = "url('../danallenfilms/images/screenshots/husky/shot2.png')";
            imgArray[2] = "url('../danallenfilms/images/screenshots/husky/shot3.png')";
            imgArray[3] = "url('../danallenfilms/images/screenshots/husky/shot4.png')";
            imgArray[4] = "url('../danallenfilms/images/screenshots/husky/shot5.png')";

    var numOfImg = imgArray.length
     function randomImg(){


         var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*(numOfImg));


            document.getElementById('imgDisplay').style.backgroundImage = imgArray[randomNum];

    };
    setInterval(randomImg(), 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
   var imgArray = []
            imgArray[0] = "url('../danallenfilms/images/screenshots/husky/shot1.png')";
            imgArray[1] = "url('../danallenfilms/images/screenshots/husky/shot2.png')";
            imgArray[2] = "url('../danallenfilms/images/screenshots/husky/shot3.png')";
            imgArray[3] = "url('../danallenfilms/images/screenshots/husky/shot4.png')";
            imgArray[4] = "url('../danallenfilms/images/screenshots/husky/shot5.png')";

    var numOfImg = imgArray.length,
        elem = document.getElementById('imgDisplay');

    setInterval(function () {
         var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*(numOfImg));
         elem.style.backgroundImage = imgArray[randomNum];
    }, 1000);
```

See the proper usage of `setInterval` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)

You may also have issues if your script is executed before the `imgDisplay` is loaded. You can fix that issue by putting the script above before closing the `body` tag.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<body onload="setInterval(randomImg, 1000);">
...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgArray = [
 "url('../danallenfilms/images/screenshots/husky/shot1.png')",
 "url('../danallenfilms/images/screenshots/husky/shot2.png')",
 "url('../danallenfilms/images/screenshots/husky/shot3.png')",
 "url('../danallenfilms/images/screenshots/husky/shot4.png')",
 "url('../danallenfilms/images/screenshots/husky/shot5.png')"
            ];

var numOfImg = imgArray.length;
 function randomImg(){
     var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*numOfImg);
        document.getElementById('imgDisplay').style.backgroundImage = imgArray[randomNum];
}
setInterval('randomImg()', 1000);
```

try as this

Answer (score 0):

To make it run on page load you need to have a function which will be called on page load. Lets name it "onStart". It will just include a single line, that is your setInterval line. Also you will have to write some js in html code. That is find your body tag and add attribute "onload". Like this:

```
<body onload="onStart()">
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your Math.random usage. Multiply the `Math.random` by `1000000` then use modulo (`%`) to get a number in a range:

```
var imgArray = [
 "url('../danallenfilms/images/screenshots/husky/shot1.png')",
 "url('../danallenfilms/images/screenshots/husky/shot2.png')",
 "url('../danallenfilms/images/screenshots/husky/shot3.png')",
 "url('../danallenfilms/images/screenshots/husky/shot4.png')",
 "url('../danallenfilms/images/screenshots/husky/shot5.png')"];

function randomImg() {
    var randomNum = (Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000000)) % (imgArray.length - 1));
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = imgArray[randomNum];

}

setInterval(randomImg, 1000);
randomImg();
```

## Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/swYcf/

## Fullscreen: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/swYcf/embedded/result/